# Custom Kernel: Implement filesystem

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems, kernel, ext2

As a out of course project, I am currently developing a kernel in an attempt to better understand all the aspects of an actual OS. So far, I am done setting up a flat physical memory model with support for paging and the basic interrupts (keyboard and perhaps trackpad/mouse next). I thought the step forward would be to implement a filesystem and I am keen about the ext2. I have looked around, even on SO but there isn't anything explicit that answers my questions:

1. Is it possible to write a driver to access an ext2 filesystem in C or do I need to go lower?
2. If I plan to access the filesystem off a USB device, I am assuming I will need to get the device driver for USB running first. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
3. I know the code for detecting a filesystem is already available on the MINIX and other kernels but what I really want to know is if I want to build a custom albeit simple filesystem, how do I go about it? I am considering this possibility too.

My apologies if the question and details sound a little ignorant but I am still in the learning process.

Thanks :)

Comment: And all this in the few hundred characters you can type in an answer box... The `ext2` driver alone in the Linux kernel is somewhat north of 8000 lines of code...

Comment: You write, that you develop a kernel ? You create a whole operating system or just a kernel ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying, twalberg. I understand the complexity of it, which is why I even asked for a guide on writing and detecting a simpler filesystem. Albertus, for now I am trying not to distinguish between an OS and a kernel. I can safely say that there is nothing about "user space".
I am not looking for explicit code but more of an abstract kickstart to the whole process.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are asking an awful lot for this kind of forum. But to more accurately answer your questions - 1) Yes - see the Linux kernel's implementation, which is in C, 2) Yes - again, Linux (or any other open source OS kernel) has USB drivers, but that's even bigger than `ext2`, and 3) look at other implementations to see how it's done.

Comment: ^Thanks a lot. My original idea was to build everything from scratch and so far I have managed custom syscalls to the tune of printing to screen and scanning. I was hoping to get my own variant of open(), close(), read() and write() going but that seems to be a little over the top given the time frame I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you a few tips/hints - a clear answer isn't that simple:

1. An ext2 filesystem written in C is just C. C is just a programming language - you can use C++, plain assembly or a few others (A few os'dever use D) - but not a "managed" language etc. But it is important that you have a rock solid understanding of this language. In my opinion assembly is a MUST (Take a look at the scheduler in an operating system -> plain assembly)
2. Do you really want to write an USB driver ? It isn't "just" a simple USB driver (Layer of abstractions). Why a USB driver and not a floppy disk or CD driver (Believe me - a floppy driver in 32 bit protected mode isn't that hard) ?
3. Please focus on your project. Of course Linux (Early versions) and Minix have example code, but take care of the design structure (Monolithic/Microkernel or hybrid-kernel) - and don't mix it, write your own code.

Please make on step after the other. You wrote a basic IRQ handling and the plan is to write a keyboard/mouse driver - write the keyboard driver ! Don't dream about loading and executing files (Rom wasn't built in one day).

You have to read documentations, for example the Intel manuals or other "books". A very popular forum is osdev.org - take a look at the wiki. As twalberg said, it's a very huge module - stay focused on the main parts of your operating system.

I know, this is not the answer to your question - but it's important not to go in the wrong direction and dream of a fancy UI or something like this ;)

[osdev.org forum](http://f.osdev.org/) 
[osdev.org wiki](http://www.osdev.org/) 
[Intel manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

And a few other books in my book shelf can you find here (Tanenbaum, Silberschatz with Peter Galvin - great books!):

[Books](http://wiki.osdev.org/Books)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
For 2: USB came up to my mind out of the blue. I was also considering emulating a floppy on a USB and writing the appropriate driver for it

I don't dream of implementing a UI of any sort but I would like to get some sort of a filesystem working on it. Or do you suggest taking up a slightly less daunting task such as process communication?

Comment: I wrote a floppy driver, but after looking back I would take "El torito". You can emulate a floppy disk or use it as a normal CD with GRUB:
http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootable_El-Torito_CD_with_GRUB_Legacy

With GRUB and a multiboot header you can load modules - take a look at it (maybe to load some parts)

Comment: Please tell me if I am on the right track here. Currently, I boot my kernel binary off a pendrive with the help of Grub. If I want to come anywhere close to implementing a filesystem, my first step will be to handle the syscalls such as open et al., before I can even go about detecting it? On the other hand, if I can manage a custom implementation, I can get a ramshackle of a filesystem?

Comment: In my opinion - GRUB is the right way to go. Don't write an own bootloader unless you have a very deep understanding of the boot process and assembly (first and second stage).

Take a look at the GRUB documentation. AFAIK GRUB can load a ramdisk as multibootheader-module - then you can read(and write) from memory and don't have to handle the whole device driver stuff